# wmi query returns empty

Tags: c#, wmi

```
var ram = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select MaxCapacity from Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().First();;
RamAmount = (uint)ram["MaxCapacity"] / 4096;
```

I got this code to get the total of install RAM. But the query returns empty, I get the error "Sequence contains no elements" what basically means the query is empty.
Anybody knows why because this program is running on 2000 other pc's and works fine.

Comment: Indeed code runs fine on my machine (windows 8.1 64 bit)

Comment: That sounds like an issue specific to that computer.  I'm assuming `new ManagementObjectSearcher("select MaxCapacity from Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray").Get().Count` returns `0`?  Are you trying to get the total installed physical memory?  I believe the `Capacity` property of the [`Win32_PhysicalMemory` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394347.aspx) is more appropriate for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got that error because the [`ManagementObjectSearcher` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx) does not provide an indexer so your code won't even compile.  You need to call the [`Get` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/67a77ef1.aspx) to retrieve the results:

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select MaxCapacity from Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray"))
using (ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get())
{
    uint ramKilobytes = results
        .Cast<ManagementBaseObject>()
        .Sum(memoryArray => (uint) memoryArray["MaxCapacity"]);

    RamAmount = ramKilobytes / 4096;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add something. This is what I call.